# How to switch guns in Mini Militia?

Tags: doodle-army-2-mini-militia

I want to switch guns in Mini Militia: if I have uzi in my hand and I have unlocked Desert Eagle double wield, I want the uzi to go back in my inventory.
I have also seen players switching guns, if they have uzi in their hand with double wield they do switch their gun to another without even seeing the other gun.

I tried searching on Google, too, but I got nothing.